# Data in table is not showing in Django admin

Tags: django, sqlite, csv

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class VilleStation(models.Model):
    nomVille = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cp = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nomVille
```

admin.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from prixcarbu.models import VilleStation

class VilleStationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('nomVille',  'adresse','cp',)
    fields = ('nomVille', 'adresse','cp',)

admin.site.register(VilleStation, VilleStationAdmin)
```

I imported a CSV file using database browser for SQLite. Table contains the data but admin page doesn't show it.

Comment: Probably the data is not in right table.

Comment: Please give details what you're doing by looking at your current code, anything can't be said since the code is right. Do you want to see CSV file data in django admin?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see empty model in admin or no model at all?

If you don't see your model in the admin at all check if you added your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

After closing my computer and reopening, the data is now visible in the admin. Probably a cache problem. Everything is fine now. Thank you all.